# Jwt verify whitout checking expiration

Tags: jwt, nestjs

I have a function which generates a refresh token.

```ts
   async refreshToken(token: string): Promise<{ token: string } | ErrorDetails> {
   if (!token)
     throw new HttpException('No token provided', HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)

   token = token.split(' ')[1]
  
   const jwtToken = await this.jwtService
     .verifyAsync(token, {
       secret: process.env.JWT_SECRET,
     })
     .catch((error) => {
       if (error === 'jwt expired') return
     })
   // Here if token is expired jwtToken is null
   if (!jwtToken)
     throw new HttpException('Invalid token', HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN)

   const user = await this.userService.findUserByAllFields(jwtToken.user)

   if (!user) throw new HttpException('Invalid token', HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN)

   const userDetails = this.userService._getUserDetails(jwtToken.user)
   const jwt = await this.jwtService.signAsync({ userDetails })

   return { token: jwt }
 }
```

I wan't to check if the token is right but without checking the expiration
Is there any way to handle it ?

Answer (score 0):

```
this.jwtService.verify(token, {
    secret,
    ignoreExpiration: true,
});
```

Answer (score -1):

If you don't pass `expireIn` option or `exp` claim there will not be any exp claim, so the JWT does not have any expiration.